Psychologist studies patient and discovers she's telepathic
It was a movie that started off about a young lady who was finishing high school and when she was at her prom I think, she started hearing voices and flipped out. 
She was taken to a mental institution and was a mess and didn't interact/talk or anything. 
Eventually a psychologist came to see her and studied her. Gave her some books to read which made a breakthrough, started coming back to reality and communicated again. 
The psychologist realized she was telepathic and took her to a place specifically for her and to help her. She then came to help work for the police. 
Does Anyone know what this movie is called? I have no idea who was in it even, was probably around 2000. 

Seems like Thoughtcrimes  from 2003. The IMDb recap fits it perfectly:

an ordinary teenage girl finds her life is never the same after her prom night when she starts to hear voices. After eight years in soiltary madness in Brookridge Mental Hospital, diagnosed as a schizophrenic, a Dr... arrives and explains that she isn't crazy. The voices are not her imagination, she is telepathic... However Dr Welles works for the National Security Agency and they want [her] to help them in the fight against the dangers to the country's security.


That sounds like a cool movie! I came up with a plot just like that, only condensed into the span of a few days, in the mid 90's. Too bad I didn't follow through with writing it!
